# Contenteditable change style between characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I think this is more of a guidance question than a right-or-wrong kind. Essentially I'm looking for the simplest/cleanest way to implement an input element that changes style (to say a different font color) between to characters (say '[' and ']') -- similar to when you comment out some code in an editor. I figured I would need to use a contenteditable div, but am not opposed to (and might prefer) other options if possible.

Right now, I'm thinking of either calling a replace function that turns the open and close brackets into open and close span tags every keyup or every few seconds, but retaining the cursor position seems to be a problem, and both options seem clunky besides.

Is there some preferred method to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance, I owe almost everything I know about code to the stackoverflow community!

Comment: Seems you need syntax highlighter.

Comment: Thanks for the direction! I found rainbow ([link](http://rainbowco.de/)), which I think will work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I have found few links that might help you

[**ETCH.js**](http://etchjs.com/)

**[CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/)**

Comment: I wasn't exactly looking for a code editor, but thanks for the contribution.